# combining and adding arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:
1st:

```
[0] => 1, 
[1] => 2, 
[2] => 1, 
[3] => 2
```

2nd:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
)
```

So i need to select values from 1st array and insert they in keys of second array and it should looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
)
```

In the end i need to make last array looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 6 
        [1] => 8 
    )
)
```

Can you help me: how can i do it? thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The array in the third code block is impossible to make since it contains duplicate keys. Also, is there any reason why the two last arrays are associative instead of indexed (since they are missing the key `0`)? Please include the logic as well. How should the values be combined and what does the first array mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want sum of same indexed value if i'm not mistaken.

```
$first = [1,2,1,2];
$second = [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2], [3,4]];

$final = [];

foreach($first as $key => $value)
{
  if(isset($final[$value]))
    {
      foreach($final[$value] as $k => $v)
            {
              $final[$value][$k] += $second[$key][$k];
            }
    }
  else
    {
      $final[$value] = $second[$key];
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($final);
```